# Does in theory spacetime holds all the data of everything?

Tags: spacetime

A Question that is bothering me lately.
In my mind spacetime has been in contact with all existing particles and continues to be in contact.

If mass bends spacetime then in quantum scale no matter how small it is there is got to be bend in spacetime and those bends are like piece of information no?

Answer (score 2):

There is active research on a correspondence between spacetime and information, but it goes the other way round, with the idea that information may give rise to spacetime via entanglement.

The catch words are "It from Qubit"; see an introduction in [this Scientific American article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/tangled-up-in-spacetime/). It is yet another venue from [the AdS/CFT correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdS/CFT_correspondence) which has been explored for many years now as a pathway towards quantum gravity.

For a critical point of view, also see [this blog post](https://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/wordpress/?p=8047).

Comment: I was always thinking that there is motion in particles as a result of spacetime movement (side effect).

Comment: @RayLuxembourg. If you have further enquiries, please write new questions. Comments are not the place for discussion.